# Unable to send email with phpMailer SMTP

Tags: php, email, xampp, smtp, phpmailer

PHP Script

```
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
//Passing true to the constructor enables the use of exceptions for error handling
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
 $mail->Port       = 25;    
 $mail->Timeout = 10;
 $mail->isSMTP();   
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; 
 $mail->Host       = 'mail1.ClientWeb.com';
 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
 $mail->Username   = 'test_mail@ClientWeb.com'; 
 $mail->Password   = 'pwd';  

 $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
 $mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
 $mail->addAddress('keprta.martin@gmail.com', 'Martin Keprta');
 $mail->Subject = 'test';

 $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
 $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
 $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
 $mail->send();
 echo "Message sent!";
  } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
                                     }
```

Problem description

Client has a script on his server which apparently runs. I am trying to connect to his server which is possible but when I try to send email following error appears

```
2017-05-07 18:31:57 Connection: opening to mail1.warmacher.com:25, timeout=10, options=array ( ) 
2017-05-07 18:31:57 Connection: opened 
2017-05-07 18:32:07 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2017-05-07 18:32:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2017-05-07 18:32:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2017-05-07 18:32:17 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 
2017-05-07 18:32:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO localhost
```

Far as I can understand that connection is estabilished but for some reason email is not send.

Steps I took prior to asking this honorable community

1. Check if security is needed - None
2. Check if port is correct - 25 is correct
3. Check if name/pwd correct - Yes. I can log into webmail on
   server

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the mail server you're connecting to. If I `telnet mail1.warmacher.com 25`, it connects, but does not respond. It doesn't appear to be a greet delay countermeasure, it's just broken. The short timeout you've set doesn't allow the maximum wait (5 minutes) that SMTP permits, though it doesn't appear to help anyway. Your code is fine - you need to get the mail server fixed.

Comment: Server should be fine. I logged with this account into webmail and send/recieve emails. I am using ISP config 3 and I have no web-gui acess into mailserver.

Comment: Webmail doesn't require SMTP - it can read over IMAP and send with sendmail. Regardless, the mail server is not responding on the port you're trying to send through. If it doesn't work through telnet, it's not going to work through PHPMailer either; this is a server problem, not a client problem.

Comment: This is what I thought. So there are two more mysteries.

Comment: 1.How is possible that on server is already functional mail sending script which is sending email
2.What kind of configuration is wrong... What kind of settings should I change on post server?
3.Is there a chance that server responds only on smtp requests on domain?

Comment: It could be sending via a different route, for example if you have a local mail server that's acting as a relay on localhost, then sending via the PHP mail() function will work. Otherwise you should check the mail logs on the server you're connecting to - if you have access to that.

Comment: I made some resarch on customer web site and find following CRON script.
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP

    $mail->Host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers

    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 

    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;       

    $mail->SMTPSecure = false;

Comment: And after i changed my configuration to that "stuff" I am recieving SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: keprta.martin@gmail.com: : Relay access denied.

Comment: I'd suggest you delete this question - it's unlikely to be much use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem caused by unknown postfix server settings.( Basically it is not a problem but a feature )
2. Curret setting does not allow access to postfix from outside of server